# How to import Prolog from pwsip

Tags: prolog

[image: Error when run the code]

I tried running this code in VISIO CODE STUDIO:

from pyswip import Prolog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

and I got an error. what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have pySwip installed, or at least it cannot be found.

I tried

https://pypi.org/project/pyswip/

Were one reads:

> WARNING! PySwip has no Windows installers! If you are a Windows user,
>   see INSTALL. There are some "free download" sites that claim to be
>   hosting PySwip installers. DO NOT TRUST THEM!

They have an `INSTALL.md` but clicking on that just leads to a 404.

but you can get it from github:

https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/master/INSTALL.md

You are on Windows, so:

> Make sure swipl executable is on the PATH.
>
> Run `pip install pyswip`